# Remove characters after underscore

Tags: python, string, arcmap

I have photo files in arc map with file names such as:
`image_name = (1-3#s)_(10#'s).jpg`. For example:

```
1_1z1z1z1z1z.jpg
599_iiiiiiiiii.jpg
```

I want to remove the 6 characters that follow the underscore (`_`), and remove (`.jpg`). For the example, the result would be:

```
1_1z1z
599_iiii
```

`image_name.strip('jpg')` removes the file extension as a simple expression, but I can't figure out how to make a combined string command in the advanced section to accommodate the second rule as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to match the first 6 characters (any 6 characters `.{6}`) after the `_` and remove them all. Then also remove the fixed `.jpg` from the result:

```
>>> name = '123_1a2b3c4d5e.jpg'
>>> re.sub('_.{6}', '_', name).replace('.jpg', '')
'123_4d5e'
```

Note that `str.strip('jpg')` is *not* a safe (or correct) way to strip the `jpg` extension. [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) will remove *all leading and trailing instances* of the characters given, for example:

```
>>> 'jppj-test-jpg'.strip('jpg')
'-test-'
```